# Tree class with template and dynamic allocation for children

Tags: c++, templates, new-operator, allocation

So I am writing a *Node* template class with n children.
My problem is in the constructor. It seems that when I want to allocate memory for an array of Node type (in Node(V data) constructor), the memory is not allocated even though I use new.

---

As you can see in this image of memory state, there is nothing on the heap.
[Memory state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bekjx.png)

Here is my code.

```
template <typename V>
class Node {
private:
  V _data;
  unsigned short _size;
  Node<V>* _children;
public:
  Node();
  Node(V, unsigned short);
  Node(const Node&); // copy constructor
  Node& operator= (Node&); // assignement by copy constructor
  Node (Node&&); // transfer constructor
  Node& operator= (Node&&); // assignement by transfer constructor
  ~Node();
};

template <typename V>
Node<V>::Node()
  : _data(0), _size(0), _children(nullptr) {}

template <typename V>
Node<V>::Node(V data, unsigned short size)
  : _data(data), _size(size), _children(new Node<V>[_size]) {}

template <typename V>
Node<V>::Node (const Node& other)
  : _size(other._size), _data(other._data) {
  _children = new Node<V>[_size];
  for (unsigned short i = 0; i < _size; i++) 
    _children[i] = other._children[i];
}

template <typename V>
Node<V>& Node<V>::operator= (Node& n){
  if (&n != this) {
    delete[] _children;
    _data = n._data; _children = n._children; _size = n._size;
    n._data = 0; n._size = 0; n._children = nullptr;
  }
  return *this;
}

template <typename V>
Node<V>::Node (Node&& n){
  _data = n._data; _size = n._size; _children = n._children;
  n._data = 0; n._size = 0; n._children = nullptr;
}

template <typename V>
Node<V>& Node<V>::operator= (Node&& n){
  if (&n != this) {
    delete[] _children;
    _data = n._data; _children = n._children; _size = n._size;
    n._data = 0; n._size = 0; n._children = nullptr;
  }
  return *this; 
}

template <typename V>
Node<V>::~Node() { delete[] _children; }



int main() {
  Node<char> n1('A',5);
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advence

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<Node<V>>` instead of raw memory management?  In addition, your `operator=` leaks memory.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/yl-jBu Are you sure this is not a bug in your IDE (or whatever produces this emoji for `nullptr`)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would like to use pure pointers because it is a school project about fundemental of c++ programming. If it wasn't this case, I would have definitly use vector and smart pointers.

Comment: @Botje I use pure g++ compiler on Arch linux (Manjaro KDE) and a text editor. I have never use an IDE while programming.

Comment: *fundemental of c++ programming* -- It is opinion that usage of pointers when you have vector is "fundamental C++ programming".  The term "fundamental" could also mean usage of STL containers and algorithms.

Comment: @Mohammadreza ... whatever produced the image, then. Try printing the address in `_children` to prove that memory _IS_ allocated.

Comment: @Botje I use http://pythontutor.com for producing the image. I also tried to print out the address of every element in the _children array but it is printing a blank line. ```template <typename V>
Node<V>::Node(V data, unsigned short size)
  : _data(data), _size(size), _children(new Node<V>[_size]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    std::cout << _children[i] << std::endl;
}``` I use this code in constructor to print out the memory addresses

Comment: @Mohammadreza Then you should file a bug with them, as I cannot reproduce this behavior *at all*, either online or offline.

Comment: That does not print addresses, that tries to print `Node` instances. For which you did not specify an actual `operator<<`.

Comment: I can reproduce what you saw in the pythontutor tool, and it's definitely mistaken.

Only issue I see in the code is the copy assignment operator parameter should be const.

Comment: @parktomatomi as you can see, altough I do a new for mu array, at the end, my pointer to array in nullptr and that is my problem. Because normally, it has to point to an array of 5 Node object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry for posting as an answer, but there's a character limit in the comments)

This is what I see when I actually step through a debugger. It runs like you expect, assigning _children a pointer, and then initializing the 5 Node objects in that space. Based on this, I believe the visualization tool you were using has a bug.

```
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at ex.cpp:64
64      int main() {
(gdb) step
65                Node<char> n1('A',5);
(gdb) step
Node<char>::Node (this=0x7ffffffedc90, data=65 'A', size=5) at ex.cpp:22
22                Node<V>::Node(V data, unsigned short size)
(gdb) step
23                : _data(data), _size(size), _children(new Node<V>[_size]) {}
(gdb) p data
$1 = 65 'A'
(gdb) p size
$2 = 5
(gdb) step
Node<char>::Node (this=0x8413e78) at ex.cpp:19
19                : _data(0), _size(0), _children(nullptr) {}
(gdb) step
Node<char>::Node (this=0x8413e88) at ex.cpp:19
19                : _data(0), _size(0), _children(nullptr) {}
(gdb) step
Node<char>::Node (this=0x8413e98) at ex.cpp:19
19                : _data(0), _size(0), _children(nullptr) {}
(gdb) step
Node<char>::Node (this=0x8413ea8) at ex.cpp:19
19                : _data(0), _size(0), _children(nullptr) {}
(gdb) step
Node<char>::Node (this=0x8413eb8) at ex.cpp:19
19                : _data(0), _size(0), _children(nullptr) {}
(gdb) step
Node<char>::~Node (this=0x7ffffffedc90, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ex.cpp:60
60      Node<V>::~Node() { delete[] _children; }
(gdb) p _children
$3 = (Node<char> *) 0x8413e78
(gdb) step
Node<char>::~Node (this=0x8413eb8, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ex.cpp:60
60      Node<V>::~Node() { delete[] _children; }
(gdb) step
0x00007fffff1013c0 in operator delete[](void*, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) step
Single stepping until exit from function _ZdaPvm,
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am convinced that the visualisation site is broken. Also could you please note which debugger are you using?

Comment: That's gdb, which is a text based debugger that goes with gcc on Linux. 

On Windows the MSVC community edition has a fantastic visual debugger as well.